# File location shows eclipse installation directory instead of eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, file, filepath

When I try to find the location of a file, it shows eclispe installation directory and displays the output as below. How to get the full path of a file in eclipse? I am stuck with this issue. Your help is much appreciated.

```
File file = new File("icon_4.png");
System.out.println(" absolute path:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Output: E:\Softwares\eclipse-jee-photon-M6-win32-x86_64\eclipse\icon_4.png

Comment: I guess the workplace directory is the eclipse directory in some way. is it?

Comment: No. Both are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a path the file is taked to be in the current working directory.

The value of the working directory is configured in the Run Configuration for your program.

Open the 'Run > Run Configurations...' menu and find the configuration for your program. Look at the 'working directory' section on the 'Arguments' tab to configure the value.